# Filtrar sobre un array de objetos con referencia a otro array JS

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de filtrar de un array de objetos arrTwo todos los elementos que tengan id diferente a los numeros del arrOne, he probado de la siguiente manera, el problema es que siempre obtengo un array vacio (no tengo muy claro el uso de filter y find);

Gracias por la ayuda

```
const arrOne = [1,2];
const arrTwo = [{id:1 ,name:'A',state:'healthy'},{id:2, name:'C',state:'healthy'}, {id:3, name:'C', state:'healthy'}, {id:4, name:'C',state:'healthy'}];

const filterByReference = (arr1, arr2) => {
   let res = [];
   res = arrOne.filter(el => {
      return !arrTwo.find(element => {
         return element.id === el;
      });
   });
   return res;
}
console.log(filterByReference(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle es que si haces ! al filter() siempre te regresa false es como si hicieras ![] . La otra es que busqueda deberia ser al revez, no? buscar en arrTwo los id que encuentren al menos una coincidencia en arrOne

```
const filterByReference = (arr1, arr2) => {
   let res = [];
   res = arrTwo.filter(x=> {
        return arrOne.filter(y=> y == x.id).length >0
   });
   return res;
}
```

En pocas palabras tienes que ver si en arrOne hay al menos 1 elemento de ser asi, retornar true.

Answer (score 1):

Esta podria ser otra opcion:

```js
const arrOne = [1,2];
const arrTwo = [{id:1 ,name:'A',state:'healthy'},{id:2, name:'C',state:'healthy'}, {id:3, name:'C', state:'healthy'}, {id:4, name:'C',state:'healthy'}];

const filteredArray = arrTwo.filter(item => arrOne.indexOf(item.id) < 0);

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Simplemente se itera usando el metodo `.filter()` como callback se pasa una funcion que valida si el `id` del objeto **No** esta en `arrOne` lo agrega al nuevo arreglo `filteredArray` (los objetos con id 3 y 4)

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona bien así:

```js
const arrOne = [1,2];
const arrTwo = [{id:1 ,name:'A',state:'healthy'},{id:2, name:'C',state:'healthy'}, {id:3, name:'C', state:'healthy'}, {id:4, name:'C',state:'healthy'}];

const filterByReference = (arr1, arr2) => {
   let res = [];
   res = arr2.filter(el => {
       return !arr1.filter(x => el.id == x).length > 0
   });
   return res;
}
console.log(filterByReference(arrOne, arrTwo));
```

**Cambios realizados:**

1. He modificado esta línea:

```
res = arrOne.filter(el => {
```

por esta otra:

```
res = arr2.filter(el => {
```

pues si quieres usar otras constantes puedas hacerlo, sino los parámetros no sirven para nada. Fíjate también en el orden de la variable, que está al revés de lo que tu hacias.

2. También he modificado esta otra línea:

```
return !arrTwo.find(element => {
```

por esta otra:

```
return !arr1.filter(x => el.id == x).length > 0
```

pues tal como @StialManstike comenta en su respuesta, la búsqueda debe ser al reves y con `filter`, pero usando `arr1` para que reconozca los valores parametrizados en la función, tal como he dicho antes.

Ejecuta el snippet adjunto y verás que funciona.